# add form field based on option selection

Tags: java, jquery, html

I have a form where i have to add form field based on options selected in the select box

what i have done is created all form fields and based on selection show hide fields , But is there any simplified way to do this

```
<select name="child" id="child">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div id="age1">                                                       
  <select name="age1" id="age1">
  //options
  </select>
</div>
<div id="age2">                                                  
   <select>
   //options
   </select>
</div>
<div id="age3"> 
  <select>
  //options
  </select>
</div>
```

here is my jquery

```
$('#child').change(function() {
 if( $(this).val() == 0 ) {     
   $("div#age1").hide();
   $("div#age2").hide();
   $("div#age3").hide();
   $("div#age4").hide();    
 }

 if( $(this).val() == 1 ) {
   $("div#age1").show();
   $("div#age2").hide();
   $("div#age3").hide();
   $("div#age4").hide();

 }
 if( $(this).val() == 2 ) {
   $("div#age1").show();
   $("div#age2").show();
   $("div#age3").hide();
   $("div#age4").hide();
 }

 if( $(this).val() == 3 ) {
   $("div#age1").show();
   $("div#age2").show();
   $("div#age3").show();
   $("div#age4").hide();
 }
 if( $(this).val() == 4 ) {
   $("div#age1").show();
   $("div#age2").show();
   $("div#age3").show();
   $("div#age4").show();
 }
});
```

How to do it in simplified way and how to get post value for this

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<select name="child" id="child">
<option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div class="myage" id="age1">                                                       
<select name="age1" id="age_1">
  //options
</select>
 </div>
 <div class="myage" id="age2">                                                  
    <select>
     //options
    </select></div>
    <div class="myage" id="age3"> <select>
     //options
    </select></div>
```

Your JS :

```
$(".myage:eq(0)").show();
$('#child').change(function() {
  $(".myage").hide();
  $(".myage:eq("+$(this).val()+")") .show();
});
```

Use Class instead of ID :)

Comment: age1 is an id of both the div and the first select - this will cause problems. I know it was that way in the OP, but it should have been corrected. :))

Comment: try my code. id doesn't matter, it will not effect in your code. let me know if you face any issue after that

Comment: of course it works in yours cos you are targetting classes and using eq(), but its still wrong to have duplicate ids for different elements.

Comment: answer edited to give the first select list different id to its parent div

Answer (score 1):

same basic approach as Prashant - but theres no need to use eq().. the divs all have ids that match the values of the select list - and note that the first select list in your current code have the same id as its parent div. This will cause an issue, but the following will fix it.

All this does is on the change of the #child select list - triggers all divs to hide (note the display none in the CSS to hide them initially) and then show the one that matches the age+value of child. I would not actually do it this way myself, but given the code you had this works. I also added options to the age select lists to give them something to show when you change the #child list.

As I said, I would not suggest doing it this way - I would suggest appending a new select list to the end of the form based on the selection  -that way you dont have all select lists just sitting there and you don't have to worry about submitting the selected value from one of the hidden lists when you submit the form. Just a thought.

```js
$('#child').change(function() {
  $("div").hide();
  $("#age"+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

```css
div{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="child" id="child">
<option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div id="age1">                                                       
<select name="age1">
 <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
 </div>
 <div id="age2">                                                  
    <select name="age2">
  <option value="c">c</option>
   <option value="d">d</option>
    </select></div>
    <div id="age3"> 
      <select  name="age2">
       <option value="e">e</option>
       <option value="f">f</option>
    </select></div>
    <div id="age4"> <select>
     <option value="g">g</option>
   <option value="h">h</option>
    </select></div>
```